# How to fix "Sign in disabled" appearing under any circumstances?

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-account

Since some time (a pair of weeks) i can't run no third party Google Sheet or Google Sheets add-on.

Trying to do so i'm forced to run through the usual authentification andon the end of it i get the alert "Sign in with Google is temporarily disabled for this app". The alert comes without a link "advanced", so it isn't possible to go around of the alert.

This happens with all Google accounts i can login into (privat account, firm's account). Noone of these accounts is a GSuite - all are just normal account created with GMail. Nobody other, who uses the same firm's account (we are a couple of users having access to it), doesn't experiencing this issue.

How can i debug and fix this issue?

**PS**: the limitation to 100 users is definitely not the problem. After i experienced this problem firtsly i thought, this could be the cause.

But after i failed to use multiple Google Sheets published publicly and having multiple users and Google Sheets addons, published in Google's official addon marketplace, and having multiple users too, i don't think, the limitation is the cause of the issue.

This is the alert coming while authentification:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related.  OP should contact the developer or company who has created the app they are having an issue with.  SO cant help you fix issues with an application you have not created.

Comment: For me it looks like an issue with Google account setup. Recommendation to ask developer of *every* app is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Google has been increased the security on Google Accounts by denying access to many apps and services that previously had access to google accounts. Google announced a forthcoming change to how apps sign in and gain access to your Google account more then a year ago, to give app developers plenty of time to conform to googles requirements regarding account access.

If an app/service is showing the `'temporarily disabled'` then the app developers need to work on getting their app verified by google in order to use Google Sign In.

More info on the security implications of allowing third-party apps and services to sign into your account and why these changes were considered necessary are provided here:

[Better protection against Man in the Middle phishing attacks](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html)

## app script addon

[Client verification app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

> Verification is `not required` for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same G Suite domain or customer.

you stated your users are not Gsuite there for the app needs to be verified before it can be used by people not on the domain of the developer who created the app.

## Unverified apps

The following image looks exactly like the screen you are seeingand taken directly from [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) documentation

[image]

The app needs to be verified there is no `debug and fix` for this issue

Comment: This is definitely not the problem. Apps, scripts and addons i'm trying to use are all in public access and have multiple users through the whole internet. Some of addons ican't use are published in the Google Sheets Addon repository and are used by everybody who installs it. After i experienced this firstly i thought like you, but after multiple cases with different publicly accessible Google Sheets and addons - no, this is not the cause.

Comment: App app scripts and addons stil have to be verified.   If the author hasnt bothered to do it yet then it is definitely the problem

Comment: I can't believe it. Mainly because of two things: i fail on using every single third-party sheet, addon or script, not SOME of them. And: no one from my colleagues experiences this issue.

Comment: I suggest you contact the developer of the App and see what they say.

Comment: All of them i contacted say different things: to re-grant access to their app (while their app is not in the list of apps with granted access), another one said, i should enable signin via Google (wtf?), even other said, i should pay for GSuite, and the next one said, he doesn't know, what happens to me, noone has reported similar issue...

Comment: See the problem is this is starting to sound like it is not your application we are discussing.  Which means this question is not programming related making it off topic for Stack Overflow.